# httponly cookie with apollo client

Tags: cookies, next.js, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo client with next.js to make authenticated request. I also use ApolloProvider to wrap on my app, as the doc suggest it : https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/

This is my ApolloClient :

```
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: API_URL,
  });

 
  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    // This work only with httpOnly = false
    const token = Cookies.get('token')
   
    // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
      }
    }
  });
  
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
```

export default client

This work fine but only when I set my cookie to httponly= false. I'm looking for a solution to get access to the cookie I set on the server side on a login request.
This is my /api/login function :

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { identifier, password } = req.body;

    const strapiRes = await fetch(`${API_URL}/auth/local`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        identifier,
        password,
      }),
    });

    const data = await strapiRes.json();
    if (strapiRes.ok) {
      // Set Cookie
      res.setHeader(
        "Set-Cookie",
        cookie.serialize("token", data.jwt, {
          httpOnly: false,
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
          sameSite: "strict",
          path: "/",
        })
      );

      res.status(200).json({ user: data.user });
    }
  } 
};
```

In a nextJS page, I can access my cookie with the getServerSideProps, but how can I do it on Apollo client?

```
function parseCookies(req) {
  return cookie.parse(req ? req.headers.cookie || '' : '')
}
export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  const { token } = parseCookies(req)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The server sends the cookie along with the response, the browser stores it and sends it along with any request to the domain of this cookie and browser will prevent any code running on it to access it.You can't have access to the httponly cookies in nextjs or any javascript framework.

why ? - Thats the purpose on HttpOnly true cookie ,this creates a secured way to store sensible information, such as authentication tokens, preventing any injected code in your page to access it.

And the getServerSideProps is run on server-side that's why you are able to access the httpOnly cookie and not on Apollo client.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly